# Fill a dataframe using a reference/lookup dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to fill one dataframe (df) with information from a lookup dataframe(reference_df). I have tried this (using other StackOverflow posts and answers) with merge, fillna and combine_first. However, each method brings some problems in my case.

df1:

```
  class  A   B   C
0     a  1 NaN NaN
1     b  2 NaN NaN
2     c  3 NaN NaN
3     a  1 NaN NaN
```

reference_df:

```
  class  A  B  C
0     a  1  2  3
1     b  2  4  6
```

Target_df:

```
  class  A    B    C
0     a  1  2.0  3.0
1     b  2  4.0  6.0
2     c  3  NaN  NaN
3     a  1  2.0  3.0
```

Three things to note:

- 'c' is not in the reference_df so should remain empty
- 'a' appears twice not ordered in df1, and should be filled with the values of 'a' in reference_df
- the order of df1 should stay as is

The above also show the issues I ran into with merging and fillna and combine_first. The repetition of 'a' breaks fillna and is filled with other values in the other two methods.

The solution I have going now is done manually via looping over both frames, but this is very expensive and the dataset is very large.

I hope I am explaining this alright, first post on StackOverflow so I might be missing some needed information. Let me know if I should clarify.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
target_df = df1[['class', 'A']].merge(reference_df, 'left')
print(target_df)
```

Output:

```
  class  A    B    C
0     a  1  2.0  3.0
1     b  2  4.0  6.0
2     c  3  NaN  NaN
3     a  1  2.0  3.0
```

Comment: Oh wow, that is simpler than I thought! Thank you so much. A short follow-up though: if my df1 has more columns I want to keep untouched (and are not present in the reference_df) do I add those in the initial square brackets?

Comment: The main thing is I don't want it trying to merge on B or C, but rather just taking those values from the reference. An alternative method of doing this would be `df1.drop(['B', 'C'], axis=1).merge(reference_df, 'left')`, this would leave all other columns intact without having to explicitly list them.